# hide div upon click, after delay

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide

I want to hide a `<div>` after clicking on it, with a delay.
I found something like this:

```
jQuery("#info.click").hide('blind', {}, 100);
```

But it doesn't do anything.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#clicker").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next("#info").toggle();
  });
});
jQuery("#info.click").hide('blind', {}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clicker">Clicker</div>
<div id="info" style="display:none;">uhhiuiu</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8ennt5g/4/)

Comment: One issue is that your selector targets `<div id="info" class="click">`, which doesn't exist in your HTML. Do you mean you want to click, then have a delay before the div is toggled?

Comment: i see the problem; yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) and the `click` event :

```
jQuery("#clicker").click(function() {
  var info = jQuery(this).next("#info");
  info.toggle()
    .delay(3000).hide('blind'); //Delay 3 secs then hide !
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#clicker").click(function() {
    var info = jQuery(this).next("#info");
    info.toggle()
      .delay(3000).hide('blind'); //Delay 3 secs then hide !
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clicker">Clicker</div>
<div id="info" style="display:none;">uhhiuiu</div>
```

Comment: @JonathanJaneta You want to hide ``#info` when you click on it ?

Comment: no, I have the clicker id to toggle the info div and then sould it hide after some time, the click on clicker sould start an timer, than after 5 sec or so the info should hide without clicking on the clicker

Comment: @JonathanJaneta done. Please try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.other-block').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

$('.specific-block').fadeIn(function () {
    $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut(1600, function () {
        alert(this);
    });
});
```

});

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/RcL5y/)